# libandroid-shmem showing invalid ELF header in chrooted linux

Tags: firefox, libraries, chroot, arm, elf

I have chrooted Debian in android marshmallow (snapdragon 650 [64bit]).

I installed iceweasel in chrooted debian. But it showed this error ::

```
(firefox:16210): Gdk-WARNING **: shmget failed: error 38 (Function not implemented)   Segmentation fault
```

So, I compiled **libandroid-shmem.so** from this [repo](https://github.com/pelya/android-shmema) using android-ndk
and copied from armv8-a folder to `/lib` directory of chrooted debian. It then asked for `liblog.so`.

```
iceweasel: error while loading shared libraries: liblog.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I copied `liblog.so` from android-ndk to chrooted debian `/lib` directory.

Now when I run `env LD_PRELOAD="/lib/libandroid-shmem.so" iceweasel`
 . It displays this error :

```
iceweasel: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so: invalid ELF header
```

Here are some details :: 
`file /lib/libandroid-shmem.so`

```
/lib/libandroid-shmem.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=5ad4582c76effbe27a6688369ad979fea5dfac2a, stripped




$ cat /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so


/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-littleaarch64)
GROUP ( /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you compile it ? I compiled and not facing any wrong elf error 
Here is my steps to compile libandroid-shmem

1. Enter into chroot
2. Clone this repository  `git clone https://github.com/pelya/android-shmem`
3. Get submodules `git submodule update --init libancillary`
4. Now, to compile it for aarch64 or arm64 you will have to make some changes in build.sh script so goto cloned repository `cd android-shmem` and delete build.sh and create new one with any text editor I am using **vi** here `vi build.sh`
5. Copy and paste this into build.sh and save

   ```
   #!/bin/sh



       gcc -shared -fpic -std=gnu99 -Wall *.c -I . -I libancillary \
                   -o libandroid-shmem.so -Wl,--version-script=exports.txt -lc -lpthread && \

   strip libandroid-shmem.so
   ```
6. Run build script `./build.sh` now you can see compiled binary in your current directory
7. Now export it `export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/your/binary`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/250784)

Comment: So should I delete ? I can edit to improve ?

Comment: If you think that the steps you took can solve the problem, then show the steps. As-is, it sounds like more of a *question* than an *answer*.

Comment: I am selecting whole code but /bin/sh is not coming in block why

Comment: Formatting in lists needs double the spacing — I just added spaces to that line.

Comment: I didn't need to adjust the `build.sh` script, but I had to ensure, that `/dev/shm` actually existed, so I bind mounted it to the tmp directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be, that you compiled the library using the android-ndk. This way it is linked against the android version of `libc.so`.

On some linux distributions `libc.so` seems to be a linker script and not an actual library, while the android-ndk apparently expects it to be a library.

However even if you replace libc.so with a symbolic link to the actual library, your compiled libandroid-shmem.so will still not work, because then it complains, that the libc version doesn't match. (I got `` /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `LIBC' not found (required by /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libandroid-shmem.so) ``)

---

Instead, compile the library directly within the chroot environment, as described in [Aux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/298708/aux)s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/454120/235929).
Note: I didn't need to change the `build.sh` script - the one provided upstream worked just fine.